# ASE reports messages as spam?

Tags: exchange-2003

Outside users are attempting to send to our domain (www.lrffpd.com). It's getting rejected sporatically.
All of the senders are getting some variation of the error "Unagi.teksnax.com has rejected the message. This message has been blocked because ASE reports it as spam". The error number varies.

- Our firewall is a Fortigate and it runs the built-in Fortigate AntiSpam software. I don't this problem is becuase of the firewall because the error is coming from the server, not the firewall.
- On the Exchange 2003 server we run ESET NOD32 for Exchange (only for AntiVirus). We also run the IMF filter built into Exchange.

I've NEVER heard of ASE and can't find any information about them.

What do you think this could be?

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here with the same setup (Exchange 2003 + ESET NOD32 + Fortigate).
When someone tries to send us and email and get this error we add the domain to the fortigate whitelist and it 'solves' the issue.
This probably means that the firewall bounces the emails.

The whitelist can be managed under UTM -> E-mail Filter -> E-mail Adress
You can accept or reject emails based on the sender address, you can use wilcard (*@gmail.com) or regexes.

In our case we just had to whitelist a dozen of domains, I'm not sure how well this would scale to thousands of domains.

Comment: What are the settings you use? Can you use expressions such as *@gmail.com for the email address?

Comment: I've edited my answer to explain how we use whitelists.

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable or change the threshold of the Fortinet firewall's Anti Spam Engine (ASE).

https://support.google.com/postini/answer/2392093?hl=en